# How to save some variables

Tags: discord, discord.js

ABOUT ME:
This question is aimed at using for a Discord bot using Discord.js
I'm used to doing coding in older coding languages like C++, C#, Batch, and Game Maker Studio, but I'm still new to Discord.js

THE INTENT:
I want to store some basic variables. Such as "Server Rupees" which is shared by everyone.
And maybe a couple others. Nothing individual. Not a database. Not an array.

THE QUESTION:
I've heard this can be done with a json file. How do I save one variable to a place I can get it back when the bot goes online again?
And once I have it saved. How do I get that variable back?

WHAT I KNOW:
Not a lot for Discord.js . My bot has about 20 different commands, like adding roles, recognizing a swear and deleting that message, kick/ban a user, bulk delete messages, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done with a json file or database,

If you are gonna go with json:

Store the value inside of a json file to start of with, for example:

`./my-data.json`

```
{ "Server-Rupees": 200 }
```

You would get the result by `requiring` the file

```js
const data = require("path-to-json.json");
console.log(data["Server-Rupees"]) 
// => 200
```

If you want to update the value, just update the property value and use `fs.writeFile`

```js
const { writeFile } = require("fs");
const data = require("path-to-json.json");

data["Server-Rupees"] += 20;

//JSON.striginfy makes the object into a string, `null, 6` makes it prettier
writeFile("path-to-json.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 6), err => {
   if(err) console.error(err);
})
```

Note: writeFile's path won't always be the same as require's path even for the same file.