# How to save an array to a file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a discord bot that includes user data inside a class, and every new object is in one array that stores all of them. I want to be able to have the same data in the array every single time I run or shut down the bot. It is perfectly fine if I have to send a command to the bot like '/save' before shutting it down. How can I do that?

Comment: there is some nodeJs componements for that...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62269962/691711

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with discord bots but in JavaScript, you cannot write to the file system due because of security constraints which means you cannot store it in a file locally. The best way to tackle this issue without using a server to write to its local file system is to use a database. So if your user array is something like this

```
[
  {
    username: example,
    age : 222,
    userId: 1
  },
  {
    username: exampleTwo,
    age : 221,
    userId: 2
  }
]
```

You can just save each key-value pair into the database in a users table:

```
| Username   | age  | userId |
| ---------- | ---- | ------ |
| example    | 222  | 1      | 
| exampleTwo | 221  | 2      |
```

This way you can also set ID to autoincrement to allow each user to be unique